# Regular Expression: Delimited Extensions

Tags: php, regex, string, file-extension

I'm trying to formulate the shortest possible Regular Expression for checking if a parameter token (in a string) contains a certain file extension.

The extensions I'd like to check for are:

```
asp,aspx,cfm,cgi,fcgi,dll,htm,html,shtm,shtml,jhtml,phtml,xhtm,rbml,jsp,php,phps,php4
```

At present, I have the following expression in place:

```
aspx?|cfm|f?cgi|dll|s?html?|jhtml|phtml|xhtm|rbml|jsp|phps?|php4
```

I'm sure there's a shorter way to do it, but I'm not a RegEx junkie, and so I'm not the best at this.

Comment: What’s wrong with `in_array($ext, explode(',', 'asp,aspx,cfm,cgi,fcgi,dll,htm,html,shtm,shtml,jhtml,phtml,xhtm,rbml,jsp,php,phps,php4'))`?

Comment: **## WHY ##??** the Regex is independent to **SHORT** and **LONG** pattern, just performance is important for using Regex. indeed, I prefer the `asp|aspx|cfm|cgi|fcgi|dll|htm|html|shtm|shtml|jhtml|phtml|xhtm|rbml|jsp|php|phps|php4` because it's not ambiguous

Comment: @Gumbo - nothing wrong with it, but there's nothing wrong with learning. :)

Comment: Regular expressions just make this unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine some of them:

```
aspx?|cfm|f?cgi|dll|s?html?|[jp]html|xhtm|rbml|jsp|php[s4]?
```

However, in my opinion your original regexp is fine. Shorter isn't necessarily better. Listing all the cases separately makes it clearer what you're doing. Merging lots of cases makes it hard to understand.

Comment: True indeed - I may land up separating them all. I just thought it may be a good idea to join them at the time, and like I mentioned in my comment, no harm in learning. But, you are right indeed. :)

Comment: Going to accept this - it looks like what I wanted. Even if I land up separating, it does answer the question. :)

Comment: @Barmar this answer is going to match a string containing `jhtm`, `phtm`, and `xhtml` as it just has to match `htm`. I was a little surprised by your critique of the other answer.

Comment: Since he's using this to match extensions, I assume it will be wrapped in something that anchors it to the end of the filename.

Comment: @hcoat - I don't see how it would match those. It's specifically checking for `jhtml`/`phtml`, and then `xhtm`. And how would it match `xhtml`?

Comment: @MikeAnthony because `s?html?` will match `htm` in any string, it doesn't care if is it `jhtml`, `phtml`, `xhtm`, `zhtm`,`shtmz`, `zhtml`,`zhtmz`,... They all contain `htm`, so if you are checking if any of these strings contains a match if will be true, unless you have anchored it which has not been shown on this page.

Comment: I see, indeed. I have anchored it on my side.

Answer (score 1):

To build an efficient pattern that begins with an alternation, you only need to take in account the first character of each alternatives. The reason is that once the first character matches, you don't need to test an other alternative. Here, if I count the number of occurence for each first character in the list, I obtain:

```
p:4
a,c,h,j,s:2
d,f,r,x:1
```

So, the pattern will look like this:

```
(?:p...|a...|c...|h...|j...|s...|d...|f...|r...|x...)
```

Now, I only need to fill each member of the alternation:

```
(?:ph(?:p[4s]?|tml)|aspx?|c(?:fm|gi)|html?|j(?:html|sp)|shtml?|dll|fcgi|rbml|xhtm)
```

But an alternation has a cost in particular at the begining of a pattern since each member of the alternation must be tested for each characters in the string, including characters that are not one of the first character in the alternation. To avoid the problem, you can use the first character discrimination technique to reduce the tests to the concerned characters.

```
(?=[acdfhjprsx])(?:ph(?:p[4s]?|tml)|aspx?|c(?:fm|gi)|html?|j(?:html|sp)|shtml?|dll|fcgi|rbml|xhtm)
```

Note: I have choosen here to sort the first characters from the more frequent to the less frequent. But if in practice, you note that for example "dll" is the most frequent you can change the position of the "d" alternative.

Note2: don't believe that a short pattern is an efficient pattern.